# How to change l10n_info() in R? UTF-8 == TRUE

Tags: r

i'm in R 4.1.2 version through R studio.

I'm having a problem with devtools() , i'm trying to create a package project in a root directory with utf-8 characters, for example:

Documents/Educación/package/my_package/

I can't change the root directory name and when i run devtools::check() it says Directory not found.

I think the problem is R console not reading my utf-8 working directory root so i want to change this values:

```
l10n_info()
$MBCS
[1] FALSE

$UTF-8
[1] FALSE

$Latin-1
[1] TRUE

$codepage
[1] 1252

$system.codepage
[1] 1252
```

So that UTF-8 is TRUE.
I'm in windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Update 18.02.22 13:48

Now i'm using fusen package to create a package and the following error appears:

```
-- Creating new directory: C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive - Universidad del Pacífico\(TRABAJO) PULSO PUCP\2022\pulso r package\pulso ---------------------------
√ Creating 'C:/Users/Lenovo/OneDrive - Universidad del Pacífico/(TRABAJO) PULSO PUCP/2022/pulso r package/pulso/'
√ Setting active project to 'C:/Users/Lenovo/OneDrive - Universidad del PacÃ­fico/(TRABAJO) PULSO PUCP/2022/pulso r package/pulso'
Error in setwd(dir = new) : cannot change working directory
√ Setting active project to '<no active project>'
```

Comment: What exactly is the code you are running and the error you are getting? Windows usually uses UTF-16 for NTFS file and directory names, not UTF-8. But how have you entered the string in R? Does the directory show up when you use something like `list.files()`?

Comment: There are reported problems between RStudio and synced folders like with OneDrive. Sometimes it work if you stop syncing while you work. Otherwise, you may try with a directory out of your OneDrive sync. You better use git with GitLab or GitHub to get a remote backup of your work.
See here for instance for OneDrive Rstudio problems: https://community.rstudio.com/t/can-no-longer-save-r-rstudio-scripts-on-onedrive-windows-rstudio-error/90292/4

Comment: Yeah basically that is what i did. As Sébastien said, there maybe some conflict with One Drive sync so i create my r package in the Documents folder and the error vanish. What a life...